# Size of a line segment

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given an isosceles triangle $ABC\ (AB=AC)$, let point $D$ be on leg $AC$. We extend leg $AB$ from $B$ side equal to $DC$. Then we join points $D$ and $E$ such that line $DE$ intersect base $BC$ on point $F$. If point $M$ is in the middle of line $AD$ prove $FM=AE/2$.
My attempt, I know if I prove point $F$ is in the middle of line $ED$, line $MF$ which joins middle of two sides of triangle $ADE$ is parallel and half size of $AE$. But I can't!

Comment: Is it possible for you to attach a figure

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Draw $\overline{DG}|| \overline{BC}$. Since $\overline{CD} = \overline{BG} = \overline{BC}$, $\overline{EF} = \overline{FD}$.

Since $\overline{AM} = \overline{MD}$, $\overline{FM} || \overline{AB}$ and $\overline{FM} = \frac12 \overline{AB}$.